# Vungle sdk for showing ad in android

Tags: android

I implemented Vungle SDK for showing ads video.its working fine.
after complete the video close button showing in corner, if i clicked then only moved to nextscreen.

but my scenario is after completion video ad automatically i have to launch next screen.How to achieve in Vungle SDK.ha

Thanks
Gowtham.R

Answer (score 0):

I am Aki from Vungle.
You want to auto-close ad after it finishes?

Most of our ads has ebd card and you need to hit "close" button to close and come back to your app. Some ads have no end-card and it will close automatically.

Please contact us at tech-support@vungle.com for any question.

Thanks,
-aki